# Perform comparison(<=, >=) operation on alphanumeric string in mysql

Tags: mysql

I have a table named "Test" contains following data

```
Name

A-00011
A-00012
A-00102
A-00202
```

and I want to fetch all record that are `'<150'`.

so anyone can help how to perform the **<=** and **>=** operation on alphanumeric string in mysql via query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by substringing to remove the first two chars, then cast to unsigned int:

```
SELECT CAST(SUBSTRING("A-00012", 3) AS UNSIGNED)
```

Your query would look something like:

```
SELECT * FROM Test WHERE CAST(SUBSTRING(myColumn, 3) AS UNSIGNED) <= 150
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *
       FROM test
       WHERE name < 'A-00150';
```

should work. (Assuming that's what you mean by "'<150'" and that all the names follow that pattern.)